# Good explaining of using PHP superglobal arrays and while/foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

Well this question actually holds 2 questions in total.

1. I want to understand a little bit more about security and handling of $_POST, $_SESSION,... security on webpages
2. Not so long ago someone told me to not use "the old" WHILE loop anymore and always the foreach even when i am querying out of a database (MYSQL).

To go back to my first question for example when i do this:

```
$var = $_POST['input'];
```

i understand that i better escape/secure some unwanted symbols i.e. " or \ just in case someone with bad intension's could do bad things. 
But i am seeing allot of different usages. Some tell me to use:

```
$var = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'input', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

others tell me to use:

```
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['input']);
```

than another one tell me to do it like this

```
$var = $_POST['input'];
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);
```

What is now the best, safest and modern way to excape and secure my arrays and variables? Do i have to secure my $_SESSION to? 
Keep in mind that i always use prepared statements if i connect, input, select & update from my mysql database using PDO.

For question 2 i trying to change al my previous (sometimes long) code to a shorter (array) way and try to use foreach and/or while with or without a function or oop class as good and much as i can. But someone told me that i better not use While and put everyting in a for > foreach loop instead. Why would you not use a while anymore and what advantage do you have with not using it anymore. Is it also really possible to fully abandon it?

Thanks in advance for the clear explanation!

Comment: In the future, please don't put two unrelated questions in a single post.  Just post two separate questions.

Comment: Someone makes a sport of it from always giving minus points to my posts? Are you really having problems reading the 2 questions? Tried to be active on a forum but if this is happening every time than it demotivates very much thanks for that!!

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but I'd like to point out that three people have voted to close it as "too broad".  (You need 250 rep to see this.)  My guess is that both the downvotes and the close votes are because you asked two questions in one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you escape stuff, the *context* is essential.

If you're inserting into a database using the (now outdated) `mysql_` functions, you use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

If you're outputting to the browser as part of an HTML document, you use `htmlspecialchars`.

If you're passing user input as a parameter to a shell function, you use `escapeshellarg`.

If you're dropping user input into a JavaScript variable, you use `json_encode`.

The point I'm trying to make here is that there is no panacea to escaping user input. It all depends on exactly what you're using it for.

---

Context is also important for loops. If you're iterating over an indexed array, you'd use a `for` loop. If you're iterating over an associative (key=>value) array, you use `foreach`. If you're looping on a condition, use `while`. All loop types have their own purpose.

Comment: You do not need to use for because it is an indexed loop, you use for if you want to use your own iterative condition, such as, only looping for the first 10 items rather than all. Foreach will loop through all values. While says.. while (this) is true, do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PDO prepared statements and [bind parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) for your input values, you don't need to, and shouldn't, do any escaping on the values.  Escaping is for when you're putting the values directly into an SQL string and they need to conform to SQL syntax (e.g. for embedded quotes within a string literal).  Bind parameters are specified separately from the SQL string, so they don't need this.

There's nothing really *wrong* with a `while` loop; the `foreach` loop is just simpler to use in the situations where it's applicable.